# My nginx main file within /usr/share/nginx/main on aws is 5.2GB in size

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I am deleting all cache files and unused files since my AWS instance reaches 100% capacity nowadays. My setup is Nginx serving though php5-fpm with opcode cache. I have enabled access_log main in the nginx conf. Should it be safe to delete this file?

Comment: `I have enabled access_log main`- sounds like there is that exact string in your nginx.conf, and thus it's using a file named "main" as the access log. [That's not the right usage of the access_log directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) - the expected syntax when specifying a log format is "access_log **path** format;". If that's not the problem: _add your nginx conf file to the question_.

Comment: Yes it was the nginx log. I had set it as "access_log main" and it was not under logrotate hence it had grown in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that file is nginx log file, so take a look inside with less and if it is, truncate it with "> main". Usually when you specify access logs you set it like this

```
access_log path_to_log_file/log_file_name.log main;
```

As you can see it here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Probably best thing to do is setup your nginx logs to be rotated so this wont be happening again (Note: You will lose old logs in process, but it looks like you don't need them anyway).